# Process a file with 1.5 billion lines in perl

Tags: perl, hash, bigdata

I need to process a file with 1.5 billion entries with 11 columns, 300GB in size. I need to extract several information from each of those lines.
I have divided the problem into two parts. First I read the file and try to reduce the file to the columns I need and some filtering. I write out this so called reduced file ~ 100GB with 700mil. entries.

Then I read the reduced file and process each entry. Here is my code segment:

```
while (my $line = <$fh_file_vss_rlrp_inst>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @columns_line = split('\s+', $line);
  if( scalar @columns_line == 10 && $columns_line[-1] !~ /X|Y|Z|K/ ) {
    print $fh_reduced "$columns_line[1] $columns_line[7] $columns_line[-1]\n";
  } 
  $inst_count++;
   if($inst_count % 10000000 == 0) { 
     $date = `date`;
     print "Processed $inst_count ... time: $date";
   }
}
```

Now reading the reduced file for further processing and I have the `%h_kI_vB` in memory with 100,000 entries:

```
while (my $line = <$fh_file_vss_rlrp_inst>) {
chomp $line;
my @columns_line = split('\s+', $line);
  my $wip = $columns_line[0];
  my $this_inst = $columns_line[0];
  my @loc_xyz;
  my @loc_ijk;
  while (grep(/\//, $wip)){
      if (exists($h_kI_vB{$wip})){ 
          push(@loc_xyz, $h_kI_vB{$wip});                         
      }
      $wip =~ s/\/[^\/]+$//;
  }
  if (exists($h_kI_vB{$wip})){
      push(@loc_xyz, $h_kI_vB{$wip});
  }
  
  if (@loc_xyz){
      my $loc_block_string;
      foreach my $loc ( @loc_xyz){
          if (not defined $loc_block_string){
              $loc_block_string = "$loc";
          } else {
              $loc_block_string = $loc_block_string.":$loc";
          }
      }
      $hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst}=$loc_block_string;
      
  }
  if(exists $hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst}) {
    my @x_y_layer = split(',', $columns_line[1]);
    $x_y_layer[0] =~ s/\(//;
    if(! defined $H_instBlock_coordinates{ $hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst} } ) { 
      my @initial_coordinate = ($x_y_layer[0], $x_y_layer[1], $x_y_layer[0], $x_y_layer[1]);
      print $fh_log "For inst:$this_inst $hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst}: @initial_coordinate\n" ;
      @{ $H_instBlock_coordinates{$hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst}} } = @initial_coordinate; 
    } else {
      my @old_x1_y1_x2_y2 =  @{ $H_instBlock_coordinates{$hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst}} };
      my $x1 = $old_x1_y1_x2_y2[0];
      my $y1 = $old_x1_y1_x2_y2[1];
      my $x2 = $old_x1_y1_x2_y2[2];
      my $y2 = $old_x1_y1_x2_y2[3];
      if($x_y_layer[0] < $x1) {
        $x1 = $x_y_layer[0];
      } elsif ($x_y_layer[0] > $x2) {
        $x2 = $x_y_layer[0];
      }
      
      if($x_y_layer[1] < $y1) {
        $y1 = $x_y_layer[1];
      } elsif ($x_y_layer[1] > $y2) {
        $y2 = $x_y_layer[1];
      }
      
      my @new_x1_y1_x2_y2 = ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
      
      print $fh_log "For inst:$this_inst Changing coordinate to block $hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst}: @new_x1_y1_x2_y2\n" ;
      @{ $H_instBlock_coordinates{$hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst}} } = @new_x1_y1_x2_y2; 
      
    }
 }
  
 $inst_count++;
 if($inst_count % 1000000 == 0) {
   $date = `date`;
   print "Processed $inst_count ...time: $date\n";
 }  
 }
```

This is horribly slow. I dispatch the job to a remote server with 450GB memory and it runs for 24 hours.
I need to optimize the code so that it's finished within 1 hour (worst case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What time does each step take?

Comment: Maybe you should consider importing this into a database.

Comment: Printing out intermediate data almost certainly incurs a pretty high IO overhead that you would avoid by merging your two processing steps.

Comment: `$fh_file_vss_rlrp_inst` really? What's wrong with `$fh`?

Comment: If we could see a sample of the file, we could perhaps come up with a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

Real performance gains are achieved by fundamentally changing one's approach. Since you have a straightforward O(N) algorithm, nothing really stands out in that department.

Below, I cleaned up your code and provided some micro-optimizations. But I doubt they'll make a big dent. And the reason is that your code is already pretty fast. You say it takes 24 hours to process 700,000,000 lines, which means that each line only takes 12 μs to process. This is reasonable.

```
  24 / 700,000,000 hour/line
* 60 minute/hour
* 60 s/minute
= 1.2 * 10^(-4) s/line
= 12 μs/line
```

You could possibly get gains from parallelization. For example, there's nothing stopping the second program from running at the same time as the first, utilizing two cores instead of 1. It would look like this:

```sh
./prog_a | ./prog_b
```

What makes it complicated to further parallelize this process is that processing a line relies on the output of the processing of earlier lines.

Still, it might be advantageous to move the processing of `$block` from `prog_a` to `prog_b`, or maybe even create an intermediary stage in the pipeline.

```sh
./prog_a | ./prog_i | ./prog_b
```

It's up to you to find the balance between the number of stages and what each stage does that produces the best result for you. For example, I guessed that it would be more advantageous to move the parsing of the 10th field of the original file to `prog_a`, so moved it from `prog_b` to `prog_a` in the versions I posted below.

But the work is still mostly sequential. The next step is dividing the work that uses `$block` across multiple cores. This can be done as long as lines with the same value of `$block` end up being processed by the same instance. I leave this to you.

---

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
   my @fields = split;
   # Using a lookup hash would be faster if you know
   # the specific values C<< $fields[9] >> can take.
   # Something like the following before the loop:
   # C<< my %skip = map { $_ => 1 } qw( X Y Z K ); >>.
   # Then, you'd use C<< !$skip{$fields[9]} >>
   # instead of a regex match.
   if (@fields == 10 && $fields[9] !~ /[XYZK]/) {
      my ($x, $y) = split(/,/, substr($fields[7], 1))
      print "$fields[1] $x $y\n";
   } 
   
   if ($. % 10_000_000 == 0) { 
      my $ts = localtime();
      print STDERR "[$ts] prog_a processed $. lines.\n";
   }
}
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Should be safe to use since it's deemed safe enough to enabled by default in Perl 7.
# Allows us to cleanly avoid repeatedly doing the same hash lookup.
# We could use a reference instead of an alias by replacing
#    \my $coords = \$H_instBlock_coordinates{$block};
# with
#    my $coords_ref = \$H_instBlock_coordinates{$block};
# and changing all other instances of
#    $coords
# with
#    ${$coords_ref}
# But this would be a lot more noisy.
use experimental qw( refaliasing );

my %h_kI_vB = ...;

my %hierarchical_blocks;
my %H_instBlock_coordinates;
while (<>) {
   my ($this_inst, $x, $y) = split;

   # C<< $this_inst >> contains something like C<< a/b/c >>

   my @loc_xyz;
   {
      my $wip = $this_inst;
      while (1) {
         # If an existing C<< $h_kI_vB{$wip}) >> won't ever be a false value
         # (zero or an empty string), replacing C<< exists($h_kI_vB{$wip}) >>
         # with C<< $h_kI_vB{$wip} >> would be a tiny tiny bit faster.
         if (exists($h_kI_vB{$wip})) {
            push(@loc_xyz, $h_kI_vB{$wip});
         }

         # The regex engine is pretty heavy, so while the
         # remainder of the loop could be replaced with
         # C<< $wip =~ s{/[^/]*\z}{} or last; >>, it
         # probably wouldn't be as fast.
         ( my $i = rindex($wip, "/") ) >= 0
            or last;

         substr($wip, $i, length($wip), "");
      }
   }

   if (@loc_xyz) {
      my $block = join(":", @loc_xyz);
      $hierarchical_blocks{$this_inst} = $block;

      # C<< $block >> contains something like C<< d:e:f >>.
      # It may have fewer parts than C<< $this_inst >> did.

      # C<< $coords >> is an alias for C<< $H_instBlock_coordinates{$block} >>.
      \my $coords = \$H_instBlock_coordinates{$block};
      if ($coords) {
         if    ($x < $coords->[0]) { $coords->[0] = $x; }
         elsif ($x > $coords->[2]) { $coords->[2] = $x; }

         if    ($y < $coords->[1]) { $coords->[1] = $y; }
         elsif ($y > $coords->[3]) { $coords->[3] = $y; }

         print $fh_log "For inst:$this_inst Changing coordinate to block $block: @$coords\n";
      } else {
         $coords = [ $x, $y, $x, $y ];
         print $fh_log "For inst:$this_inst " .                         "$block: @$coords\n";
      }
   }

   if ($. % 1_000_000 == 0) {
      my $ts = localtime();
      print STDERR "[$ts] prog_b processed $. lines.\n";
   }
}
```